# Logcat doesn't show anything of a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, logcat

I am learning about Fragments in Android and I have a problem with Logcat.

I have 2 Activities and 2 Fragments, with their Layouts:

PlayerActivity - PlayerFragment / activity_player - fragment_player

LibraryActivity - LibraryFragment / activity_library - fragment_library

I have a button in PlayerFragment to LibraryActivity, where I inflate LibraryFragment. The problem is when I am in LibraryFragment Logcat doesn't show anything.

This is the Intent that I use to call to LibraryActivity (This button is in PlayerFragment in the method onActivityCreated)

```
final Button to_library = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.library);
        to_library.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LibraryActivity.class);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
```

LibraryActivity:

```
public class LibraryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.library, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

LibraryFragment

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "test";

    public LibraryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onAttach");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container,
                false);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreateViewLibraryFragment");
        /*
         * Aquí podemos seleccionar las Views contenidas en el Layout para
         * trabajar con ellas, por ejemplo con: TipoView miView = (TipoView)
         * rootView.findViewById(R.id.miViewXML);
         */
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onActivityCreatedLibraryFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStart");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDetach");
    }

}
```

Here is where I have the problem.

Logcat doesn't show the message "onActivityCreatedLibraryFragment". I have the methods onStart(), onResume(), onStop(), etc., with their "Log.v" and I have the same problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

activity_library.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jgutierrezgil.bmusic.LibraryActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_library.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jgutierrezgil.bmusic.LibraryActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 1**: I have completed the code of LibraryFragment and I have added activity_library.xml and fragment_library.xml

Comment: I dont think you are able to start another activity or are you??

Comment: did you activity changes when button click ?if so can you please post your fragment on create view code?

Comment: Can you post the code for `activity_library.xml`?

Comment: LibraryActivity starts correctly and I can print messages in Logcat from this class. The Layout starts too (I have added buttons and some controls to check this) but the code in LibraryFragment isn't executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never actually add `LibraryFragment` to your code.  You are only adding `PlaceholderFragment`, which is leftover from the tutorial you did.

In the `onCreate()` of your `LibraryActivity`, make the following changes:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                //.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
                .add(R.id.container, new LibraryFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

The `PlaceholderFragment` is defined at the bottom of `LibraryActivity` and is meant as a dummy.  The reason the proper layout is showing up is because you changed the inputted layout file to `R.layout.fragment_library` for the `PlaceholderFragment`, giving the appearance that it inflated the proper `Fragment`.